# Can I reserve my favorite graveyard / burial ground / cemetery for myself?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, grave

There is a [similar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9752/should-can-a-muslim-make-arrangements-for-his-grave-before-dying) question out there which asks if one can make arrangements for his grave in particular. But, my question is different.

I've heard from people who say, some old people told to their young ones that *"Dear, If I die, please bury me in that graveyard next to that xxx street."* And some other people saying the same but with this thing in the end *"because that seems good and beautiful"*.

Is this sort of behavior allowed in Islam?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Note**: This is a contemporary made up issue and hence needs to be dealt carefully</sub>

---

2 points to prove **even if you reserve your grave** as you reserve your table for dinner, it is **useless**.

## 1

> Verily, Allah! With Him (Alone) is the knowledge of the Hour, He sends down the rain, and knows that which is in the wombs. No person knows what he will earn tomorrow, and **no person knows in what land he will die**. Verily, Allah is All-Knower, All-Aware (of things). (Qur'an [31:34](http://quran.com/31/34))

## 2

> Ahmad and Tirmidhi report on the authority of Ali ibn Abu Talib that the Prophet (saws) said: "O Ali, never delay three things: prayer when its time approaches, **the funeral when death is confirmed**, and marrying a widow or a divorcee when a suitable match is found for her. [Here](http://gowister.com/islam-answer-2587.html)

Also a [similar](http://www.sacred-texts.com/isl/bukhari/bh2/bh2_402.htm) Hadith which demands us to hurry in the burial process.

Since we do not know where will we die, and considering the Hadith in which prophet Muhammad (pbuh) suggested that one's body should be buried quickly and what I'm trying to prove here is,

1. If the person dies far away from where he reserved his grave, cancel the reservation and bury him at the nearby burial ground at his place of death.
2. If he dies nearby his reserved grave, there is no problem in burying him in his reserved grave. But, but and but, the person should not be waiting near his reserved grave waiting for his death as that is not allowed. (Remembering death is suggested but not anticipating and waiting for it cuz I think it is a soft form of '*suicide*'). He should migrate if he has to migrate.

Even if you fulfill that person's wish of burying him in his favorite nice quality soil reserved grave, it doesn't make the slightest difference at all. In fact, after his death, I don't think he will ever be feeling contented seeing his worldly desire getting fulfilled.

In short, **intention matters**. It depends with what intention you're reserving. And conditions apply.* Cuz they're many. I'll stop it here.

May the creator guide us all.

---

<sub>**Note**: The Hadith in '2' is in different forms e.g. [here](http://ahadith.co.uk/permalink-hadith-2036) which uses the words *" funeral when it is ready"*, but the intent remains the same (hurry in burial after death) which can be proved by using other relevant Hadith.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine to select a burial spot because you like it better. There is no hadith in Islam, nor an Ayah that forbids such actions. Each person should always reserve for their grave to help erase the burden on others as stated in this good [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/9760/12537).